# Firestore query document where object key exists

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I am writing an app that keeps track of events.  I'm using firestore to have a main collection of `events` which houses each event as a document.  Each document has its own details (including a `roles` object) and their own collection of steps within the event.

The collection object looks like this:

```
events > [collection]
    eventid1 > [doc]
        steps > [collection]
        location: "Even Center",
        notes: "Some notes here",
        timestamp: 1272153600,
        title: "A great event",
        roles:
            userID1: 0, //numbers to define role type
            userID2: 1,
            userID3: 1,
```

What I'm trying to do is query any event where `roles.userID1` exists.  I know firestore does not have sub-collection querying, so this is the closest I have come to solving this.

There are only 3 "roles" (0 = owner, 1 = editor, 2 = viewer).  I tried writing three queries and combining the queries using `.where("roles." + this.user.uid, "==", 0)`.  This would work (though I had some array issues after the fact) but I don't want to have to make 3 calls per user viewing this.

I saw in a random comment somewhere you can use the query `.where("roles." + this.user.uid, "<", "")`, but this did not work for me.

Is there a way to write a query that is able to see if a key within an object exists?

Comment: Wow... After reading my question over and over again, I realized I set myself up perfectly by using numbers as roles.  I'm using the query `.where("roles." + this.user.uid, "<", 3)` now.  which finds any event where the user id is present and has a role

Answer (score 10):

You can use `orderBy` to find documents where an object key exists. For example, let's say you have a document that looks like this:

```
{
  "users": {
    "bob": {},
    "sam": {},
  }
}
```

You can find all documents that contain `users.bob` like this:

```
.orderBy('users.bob')
```

Comment: This is exactly what I've been looking for. This should be bumped up. Thanks Johnny.

Comment: The issue with this approach is that you will need to create an index for every user (users.bob, users.sam, etc.). Though please correct me if I'm wrong, because I really wish this approach would work.

Answer (score 5):

As my comment stated above, I was able to answer my own question because I accidentally set myself up for success.

Early on, I decided to give my roles a number value, rather than a string value.  0, 1 and 2.  Now seeing that, I was able to realize that I can use the `.where` clause efficiently just by using `< 3`.

My query now includes `.where("roles." + this.user.uid, "<", 3)`.

This effectively looks at the sub-object of roles (the whole string would be something like `.where("roles.ehHH-scSd-d222-njsl-LLewS, "<", 3)`.  (3 being not a role, so if you have more than 3 roles, bump the number).

Comment: I have the same document structure and I query the docs in the same way, slightly different as I use string roles: `.where(\`users.${this.$currentUser.id}\`, '>', '')`, but I can't make a security rule for `list` operation, only for the `get` operation. Were you able to write a security rule?

Comment: @LucaFaggianelli I ended up having array of userIds that I can check for `contains` in list operations, and in addition `roles` object that is a map between userId and role. This unfortunately duplicates the user ids, but I couldn't figure any other way around it.